# Visual Studio Code clangd Find all references only works for local folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, clangd

I have a project with source files in multiple folders. I am using clangd as my language server. I have a single cmake file at the top of my source folder (I actually don't use cmake to build my project, I only use it to generate the `compile_commands.json` to allow clangd to know the include directories and the other files in the project). My cmake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.12)
project (Template)
# Generate compile commands database
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "")

add_library (Template_Lib    afw/afw_can_manager.c
                                    afw/can_router.c
                                    afw/can_router_config.c
                                    afw/hw_user.c
                                    afw/VIN_check.c
                                    afw/model_wrapper.c
                                    app_config/output_table.c
                                    model/Model_ert_rtw/Model.c
                                    model/Model_ert_rtw/Model_data.c
                                    constant_data/codegen_source/constant_data.c
                                    application/j1939_data_integrity.c
                                    application/service.c
                                    application/user_interface.c
                                    MTCT/J1939_var.c
                                    MTCT/rtU_rtY.c
                                    MTCT/Rx_gen.c
                                    MTCT/RX_sig.c
                                    MTCT/Tx_gen.c
                                    MTCT/DM1_table.c
                                    MTCT/nvam_config.c)

target_include_directories (CM2723_Template_Lib PUBLIC  pfw
                                                        application
                                                        app_config
                                                        afw
                                                        constant_data/codegen_source
                                                        model
                                                        model/Model_ert_rtw
                                                        MTCT)
```

From the CMakeLists.txt, you can see the project structure. You can also see that there is no other build files in the subdirectory. When opening a file in a subdirectory (e.g. `application/user_interface.c`), the include files are found in the other directories so the generated `command_compile.json` located at the top level of the source directories. But if I try a `Find all references` for a function, it will find the function references in files located in the same directory but it won't find the ones in other directories (e.g. `afw` directory).

`command_compile.json` looks like this (removed paths and replaced with ...):

```
[
{
  "directory": ".../source/build",
  "command": "C:\\PROGRA~2\\MIB055~1\\2022\\BUILDT~1\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang.exe -I.../source/pfw -I.../source/application -I.../source/app_config -I.../source/afw -I.../source/constant_data/codegen_source -I.../source/model -I.../source/model/Model_ert_rtw -I.../source/MTCT -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt -o CMakeFiles\\Template_Lib.dir\\afw\\afw_can_manager.c.obj -c ...\\source\\afw\\afw_can_manager.c",
  "file": "...\\source\\afw\\afw_can_manager.c"
},
{
  "directory": ".../source/build",
  "command": "C:\\PROGRA~2\\MIB055~1\\2022\\BUILDT~1\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang.exe -I.../source/pfw -I.../source/application -I.../source/app_config -I.../source/afw -I.../source/constant_data/codegen_source -I.../source/model -I.../source/model/Model_ert_rtw -I.../source/MTCT -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt -o CMakeFiles\\Template_Lib.dir\\afw\\can_router.c.obj -c ...\\source\\afw\\can_router.c",
  "file": "...\\source\\afw\\can_router.c"
},
...
]
```

As an example, when looking for all the references to the function `application_specific_initialize` from the file `application/user_interface.c`, I get:
[image: find all references]

But when I search for the function name as a string, it is also found in `afw/model_wrapper.c` which is a valid function call but in a different folder (disregard the wrong matches):

[image: search]

Comment: What do you use to compile the code? If you delete `.cache` and restart VSC, does it say anything interesting in the clangd log tab? Any parsing failures?

Comment: You should compile it with Clang at least once, and write down the working commands to the JSON. I wouldn't trust CMake to do it if you didn't check that it compiles successfully.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat deleting the ```.cache``` folder resolved the issue. I guess clangd had an old index. I use the MSVC clang 13.0.1 to compile the code. But that is just to allow clangd to know the compile flags and to know about all the files in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

To include the other directories in the search, add their absolute paths (`${workspaceFolder}` is a [predefined variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) in VS Code) to either your user (`ctrl+,`) or workspace (`.vscode/settings.json`) settings via `clangd.fallbackFlags`:

```json
{
  "clangd.fallbackFlags": [
    "-I",
    "${workspaceFolder}/afw",
    // etc...
  ]
}
```

Then restart the clangd language server.

Comment: Thanks @Mark G. Unfortunately, my issue is not with includes, it is in finding references. I have added two pictures to my question: one with find references and one with a string search. You'll see there that there is an additional reference in afw/model_wrapper.c that is not found in the original reference.

Comment: Please note that `"clangd.fallbackFlags"` is only used if **no** `compile_commands.json` file is found. A more common way to add additional include paths, which augments any command from `compile_commands.json`, is https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#add. (Even better, of course, is to ensure the commands in `compile_commands.json` contain all the needed include paths to begin with.)